# Border problems with inline-block table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I need an advice with table design :)

I want to create a table that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HZh7T/ with expand/collapse rows. For the example above I used table tags with **rowspan** which are not hierarchic i.e. the `<td>` of a single row exist in many `<tr>` so it is not easy to expand/collapse it in Javascript since I'll have to fix the rowspan dynamically every time I expand/collapse a row.

So I was thinking I should use another table with **inline-block** style DIVs. see here http://jsfiddle.net/9G9A5/1/ in this table the rows are hierarchic and I can expand/collapse easily (see example). My problem is that I'm unable to put a proper border lines as I did in the first example. The lines are all mix up.

Any advice on how to add border to second example? or maybe **inline-block** is not the way to do it?